# What is wrong with my custom token to embed entities via token?

Tags: 8, tokens, input-formats

Edit: I guess it has something to do with the info part:

```
function mymodule_token_info() {
  $info = array();
  $info['types']['embed'] = array(
    'name' => t('Embed'),
    'description' => t('Embed entities via token.'),
  );
  $info['tokens']['embed'] = array(
    'name' => t('Embed entities using embed:node:nid:viewmode'),
    'description' => t('Embed entities'),
    'dynamic' => TRUE,
  );

  return $info;
}
```

---

I wrote a small module to allow embedding entities, such as nodes, via token:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function mymodule_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data, array $options, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata) {
  $replacements = [];

  if ($type == 'embed') {

    // return $replacements;

    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      $args = explode(':', $name);

      if (count($args) > 1) {
        $entityType = $args[0];
        $entityId = $args[1];
        $viewMode = isset($args[2]) ? $args[2] : 'full';

        $entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entityType)->load($entityId);
        $viewBuilder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder($entityType);
        $renderable = $viewBuilder->view($entity, $viewMode);

        $replacements[$original] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($renderable);
      }

      // @todo: use cache bubbleable_metadata better
    }
  }

  return $replacements;
}
```

The token [embed:node:1] actually works fine.

For some reason though, I get the error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type
>   Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup as array in
>   /modules/token/src/Token.php on line 89

when saving any node, sometimes even regular admin pages/ forms. Uninstalling my module fixes the issue.

Is something wrong with how I return the replacements?

Token.php:

```
/**
 * Extracts data from the token data for use in array_multisort().
 *
 * @param array $token_info
 *   List of tokens or token types, each element must have a name key.
 *
 * @return string[]
 *   List of the names keyed by the token key.
 */
protected function prepareMultisort($token_info) {
  $by_name = [];
  foreach ($token_info as $key => $token_info_element) {
    $by_name[$key] = $token_info_element['name'];
  }
  return $by_name;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the example : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_token_info/8.3.x

Inside tokens there must be 3  levels, tokens][token_type][token].

Also tokens don't usually work like that and it will not be possible to validate that token, it is always a token type and that has tokens, which can have a type which then again has tokens. So you'd need to define types for your nested structure.

Not quite sure why you aren't using the entity_embed project to inject tokens, I assume this is supposed to be used inside a formatted text. https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed

Comment: the entity embed is not quite what i was looking for. i ended up writing an own filter though. using tokens for that really is the wrong use case. thanks!